# How to run cmd through LabView that will stop or start a Windows service?

Tags: cmd, windows-services, labview

I need to **start or stop** a Windows servicy through ***LabVIEW***. In order to do that, i need to run **cmd** as  administrator. Actually I didn't know how to run **cmd** as an admin through ***LabVIEW*** so I created another **cmd** by way described [here (OPTION TWO)](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3718-elevated-command-prompt-shortcut.html). After that I need to type "net start SERVICE_NAME" or "net stop SERVICE_NAME", but I dont know how to programmatically run one of those commands . How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the following toolkit from Grovf.

http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/215588

Answer (score 1):

I would use System Exec.vi. Instead of following option two in your link for a command window shortcut, follow those same instructions for your LabVIEW executable (or for your development environment if you are not making an executable). Thus, whenever you access System Exec.vi in your program, it inherits admin privileges.

[Here is some more reading on System Exec.vi](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/87FCE111FD854484862572FF007D252A)